# html pre-formatted text

Tags: html

i have to show * something like this using c# on web page

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Must - resist - smartass - solution `printf("*<br>**<br>***....")` (or whatever the C# equivalent is)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<pre>` tag which preserves newlines

demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2jSk8/1/

or you can just convert newline character to `<br />`